# C# Start a non-blocking background thread that waits for a condition=true then acts on it

Tags: c#, task, nonblocking

I need to check a condition and wait until it is true, then do something after it is true of it times out. But I want that to NOT BLOCK so the main thread can keep going.

I have the following method:

```
public static bool IsArrayEmptyThread(string arrName, int timeoutSecs = 30)
    {
        bool arrEmpty = false;
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var t = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (arrEmpty = !ArrayManager.IsArrayEmpty(arrayName) && sw.Elapsed.Seconds < timeoutSecs)
                {   };

                EmailManager.SendEmail("me@example.com", "me@example.com", "testing", arrEmpty.ToString() + "<br>" + "Ran");

                return arrEmpty; 

            }
           );

        return arrEmpty;
       }
```

From the main thread, I just call this method and keep going doing other things.

However, the email only ever goes out when the exe's execution is done. Moreover, if I remove the return statement right after the email call, email never comes.

Again, I just want to call that method as a non blocker, let it do it's thing, while the rest of the program keeps going, but I don't want it to wait until the execution is done for it to do what it needs to.

Thanks!

Comment: That code is burning 100% core, that is never correct.  You can't get good advice from a "that's the completely wrong to do it" starting point.  Just don't do it.

Comment: To wait for something to happen in a thread without wating resource use a ManualResetEvent, call WaitOne on your thread and when the condition is met somewhere else call Set() on the event.

Comment: Unless `ArrayManager` provides some mechanism to signal that an array is empty or has some kind of event you can hook into to know when changes have happened, your only option is to poll. I suggest you first look at `ArrayManager` to see if you can improve its interface, e.g. have ArrayManager.IsEmpty(foo) return something you can wait on not a bool.

Comment: Also, you cannot return `arrEmpty` from your synchronous method and expect it to be consistent with the value assigned by your background thread (which could start its processing before or after `IsArrayEmptyThread` returns).